# Xcode constraints Stack Views

Tags: xcode, layout, constraints

I am trying to add constraints for the following to enable the buttons and label to adapt their size and font size to different screen sizes however everything I have tried so far has not worked, even when using Stack Views.

Could anyone help with this?

[Storyboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unsj.png)

Comment: To help you solve your issue, you need to be more specific and provide with what you've got so far. If this is a matter of understanding constraints, I think the best way is to check out some nice tutorials.

Comment: One thing I finally discovered is the ability to make elements a percentage width/height of another element. (@Rikard I tried numerous tutorials and got more lost than helped, so I can understand Ella's desire to ask a question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My "breakthrough" in understanding and enjoying constraints was when I learned how to use the Constant and Multiplier attributes.

The four buttons appear to be about 80% of the width of the device. So, you could make a constraint between a button and the view and select "Equal Widths". Then, select the constraint and look at the Attributes Inspector. Change the Multiplier to 0.8 or whatever value you like. You will still need to set other constraints, such as center horizontally in container.

You could something similar with the horizontal buttons.

As for the text in the buttons, I needed this, too, and finally found the following (Objective-C):

`button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;`